# Instantiating a class using companion object

Tags: scala

Using companion object throws ambiguous reference error in REPL (spark-shell 2.1.0) when an instance of class is initialized (issue 4165 in 1.x.x closed). 
I see this error in Spark 2.1.0 (see below).

```
scala> :pas
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class X {
  var m : Long =0
  def add(x: Long): X = {
    m += x
    this 
  }
}
object X {
  def apply(x:Long) = new X().add(x)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class X
defined object X

scala> val v = X(2)
<console>:26: error: reference to X is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import $line14$read.X
and import INSTANCE.X
       val v = X(2)
               ^
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Well.. what is `INSTANCE.X`? This compiles just fine on its own.

Comment: This works fine in Scala `2.12.1`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define companion object like this in shell. You need either an object wrapper

```
object myWrapper {
  class X {
    var m: Long = 0
    def add(x: Long): X = {
      m += x
      this 
    }
  }

  object X {
    def apply(x:Long) = new X().add(x)
  }
}

import myWrapper._
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the use of a wrapper. But it works all right when I do not have the add(x) in the companion object. Also, curious to know why is this so and do you suggest another option .. as you wrote "You need either an object wrapper " or?